# Is pranayam compulsory in Sandhyavandanam under any situation?

Tags: vedic-rituals, sandhyavandanam

I have a runny nose do I have to perform Pranayama and if yes then how. If I should wash my hands again and again or should I just recite the mantra? and what about people with Asthma and similar breathing problems how should they perform Pranayama?

Comment: In case of illness, you can do Pranayam mentally ... In fact it is used to cleanse pranic body and energize ourselves with prana. You may imagine that prana tatva is entering the body, removing all diseased energy and sins and moving out of our body.

Comment: it's a cirlce :) if you do pranayama, it will cure runny nose and asthma. maybe u can reduce the duration of kumbhaka (holding breath) if you're sick, but otherwise shastras are strict about maatras (duration) to inhale/exhale/hold. also, u can just touch ur hand with water instead of fully washing, and then touch ur nose & ear (that is a shortcut achamanam that shastras allow when we yawn or pass gas or sneeze) - u might have seen elders do it.